# How to return nil for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, chat

I am making a chat application where in my app there are some limits to show messages. If a user is not subscriber he will see only 3 messages in uitableview. I want to show only 3 messages to the user and unlimited sender messages. There are 2 cells in my tableview, one for sender and 2nd for receiver. This is my conditions.

This is showing receiver cell with default value which is blank. Please guide me how to print only 3 messages which does not effect on the another cell.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            print(indexPath.section)

        if indexPath.section == 0
        {
            let model = senderMessageArray[indexPath.row]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! CellTwo
                if (model.sender_id == AppData.user_id()!)
                {
                  //SENDER
                    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    let lbl_send = cell.viewWithTag(11) as! UILabel
                    let lbl_date = cell.viewWithTag(12) as! UILabel
                    lbl_send.text = AppData.base64Decode(base64: model.message!)
                    lbl_date.text = AppData.TimeDateFormat(date: model.datetime!)

                }
             return cell
        }
        if indexPath.section == 1
         {
           //RECEIVER

            let  cellTwo =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ConversationTableViewCell
                let model = receiveMessageArray[indexPath.row]

                    cellTwo.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                   let lbl_send =
                    cellTwo.viewWithTag(22) as! UILabel
                    let lbl_date = cellTwo.viewWithTag(23) as! UILabel
                    lbl_send.text = AppData.base64Decode(base64: model.message!)
                    lbl_date.text = AppData.TimeDateFormat(date: model.datetime!)


            return cellTwo
        }
        else
        {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

    }



func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        print("sections: \(section)")
        print("receive Messages Count : \(receiveMessageArray.count)")
        print("senderMessageArray Messages Count : \(senderMessageArray.count)")
        print("Total Messages Count : \(conversationChatMessages.count)")
        if section == 0
        {
            return senderMessageArray.count
        }
        else{

            return receiveMessageArray.count

        }

    }
```

Appending array according to the limit

```
conversationChatMessages = Mapper<Chats>().mapArray(JSONObject: chatObject)!

                for receiveSms in conversationChatMessages
                {
                    if receiveSms.sender_id !=  AppData.user_id()!
                    {

                        if (conversationData?.daysleft == 0)
                        {
                            if (todayLimit < 4)
                            {
                                self.receiveMessageArray.append(receiveSms)

                                todayLimit += 1
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            self.senderMessageArray.append(receiveSms)

                    }
```

the problem is iam getting all the sender messages first then receiver messages not in the sequence

[image]

Comment: You control how many cells appear in the `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` data source methods.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your post and title don't really match.

Comment: rmaddy there is whole messages count in numberOfSections

Comment: Koen simply i have a tableview with 2 cells i want to show less data in cell 1 (make some limit for cell1 )

Comment: The logic for limiting the number of cells should be placed in the 'numberOfRows' method

Comment: ZeMoon please guide me a way to this , i want to show all records of cell1 but want to show only 3 record of cell2 how to do ?

Comment: @Jhony where is cell1 in your code?

Comment: cell is cell1 in my code

Comment: Maybe a screenshot will be helpful - it is very confusing what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: Maybe you need to use a `UICollectionView` with rows and columns ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen to what rmaddy said. You should *not* be making these decisions in `cellForRowAt`. That's not how table views work.

If you want to change whether a cell is to exist, you change your *model* so that `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` return different answers. By the time `cellForRowAt` is called, it's way too late: there *will* be a cell at this row, and your job is to supply it.

Again, if you want to change whether the cell to appear in, say, row 1 is an A-Cell or a B-Cell, you change your *model* so that when `cellForRowAt` is called, it will supply the correct cell type and data.

Comment: Piling on here, rmaddy and matt are correct. You **cannot** return nil in `cellForRowAt()`.

Comment: i understand your logic that everything done from cellForRowAt , but how i can apply this logic to return different count for both cells confusing

Comment: Make two sections

Comment: Everyone is giving good advice.  I would suggest going a stage further and producing a filtered array from `conversationChatMessages` and then you can return the number of rows in that and create the cells based on that.

Comment: "but how i can apply this logic to return different count for both cells confusing" You're confused because you are not thinking about the right thing. Think about your _model_ - what it needs to be, what it might need to be changed to, and so on. Your implementation of the data source methods should be _trivially simple_ - it is the _model_ that needs to be nimble, but the data source methods should trivially interrogate it and not make any decisions

Comment: i have updated my code with the logics of the sections now the problem is i am not getting messages in sequence

Comment: @Jhony: What do you mean by 'sequence' ?

Comment: Koen it mean its printing all the messages of the receiver first then it print the messages of the sender

Comment: Then you need to change your model. Also, maybe this is useful: https://messagekit.github.io

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers are correct, but perhaps this will help convey the point.

Define a model

```
struct ConversationViewModel {

    private var chatMessages = [ChatMessage]()

    func rowsInChat() -> Int{
        return chatMessages.count
    }

    func messageFor(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> ChatMessage{
        return chatMessages[indexPath.row]
    }

    func setChat(_ chatMessages: [ChatMessages] {

       var finalMessages = chatMessages.filter{ $0.senderId == viewer }
       var notMyMessages = chatMessages.filter{ $0.senderId != viewer}.sorted(by: {$0.date < $1.date } )

       var limit = notMyMessagescount > accountLimit ? accountLimit : notMyMessagescount

       finalMessages.append( notMyMessages[0..<limit] ).sorted(by: {$0.date < $1.date } ) 
       chatMessages = finalMessages

       //should probably notify VC that data changed
   }

}

struct ChatMessage {

    let senderId : String
    let message : String
    let date : Date
}
```

populate the model

```
 let messages = [
            ChatMessage.init(senderId: "1", message: "hi", date: Date()),
            ChatMessage.init(senderId: "2", message: "yo", date: Date().addingTimeInterval(1.0)),
            ChatMessage.init(senderId: "1", message: "you code bro?", date: Date().addingTimeInterval(2.0)),
            ChatMessage.init(senderId: "2", message: "fo sho", date: Date().addingTimeInterval(3.0)),
            ChatMessage.init(senderId: "1", message: "let's get a beer", date: Date().addingTimeInterval(4.0)),
            ChatMessage.init(senderId: "2", message: "nah", date: Date().addingTimeInterval(5.0)),
            ChatMessage.init(senderId: "2", message: "you can't see this, its my 4th response", date: Date().addingTimeInterval(6.0)),
        ]

let model = ConversationViewModel()
model.setChat(messages)
```

and implement in table view data source

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return model.rowsInChat()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let message = model.messageFor(indexPath)
    if message.senderId == userID {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! CellTwo
        cell.load(message)
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell =tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ConversationTableViewCell
        cell.load(message)
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: This is going to result in the messages being out of order because they are split into two arrays and then one array is just added onto the end of the other one.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth not sure I follow.  My example isn't splitting or appending arrays.  The OP was asking how to limit cell count, but was attempting to do so in cellForRowAtIndex. My example focused on moving data decisions into a model of some sort to create some separation of responsibilities. The model can be adapted easily for multiple arrays (maybe from different senders), can include dates for sorting, etc...  It was the design pattern I was focusing on

Comment: Sorry my bad.  The concept of the data model is fine.  What I meant is that you filter the array down to get the counts and then further limit the count of other messages to 3 if needed.  So a 10 item array could end up with a row count of 7.  You then access directly back into the original array.  So if your filtered results were items 0,1,2,4,5,7 & 10 thus a row count of 7 how would you know that?  You would just know that 7 items were needed and could end up accessing 0,1,2,3,4,5 & 6.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth That's a good point!  I did that in haste and will update later today.  nice catch.

Comment: No problem and as you said it's really more the concept of the data model that's important for this answer the actual implementation could vary depending on other needs.

Comment: Updated example... note this was done in browser so syntax errors may exist